# Display Recordset in New Form

Tags: ms-access, vba

The following code takes a parameter from a form and passes it to a stored procedure in vba. I am returning the values correctly and the stored procedure works when using debug.Print. Now I need to display the results of the stored procedure in the form "cat_percent_match". All this happens when the button is clicked. The code below does open the form, but now I need to pass the record set to it and display the results.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Dim Cmd1 As ADODB.Command
Dim lngRecordsAffected As Long
Dim rs1 As ADODB.Recordset
Dim intRecordCount As Integer
'-----
Dim cnnTemp As ADODB.Connection
Set cnnTemp = New ADODB.Connection
cnnTemp.ConnectionString = "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=***;" & _
"Trusted_Connection=No;UID=***;PWD=***;" & _
"Initial Catalog=IKB_QA;"
cnnTemp.ConnectionTimeout = 400
'Open Connection
cnnTemp.Open
Set Cmd1 = New ADODB.Command
Cmd1.ActiveConnection = cnnTemp
'---
With Cmd1
Dim localv As Integer
Dim inputv


localv = [Forms]![Start]![Selection]![cat_code]
.CommandText = "dbo.ix_spc_planogram_match_cat_percent " & inputv
.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
Set inputv = Cmd1.CreateParameter("@deptcode", 3, 1, 10000, localv)
Cmd1.Parameters.Append inputv
Set rs1 = Nothing
Set rs1 = Cmd1.Execute

DoCmd.OpenForm "Cat_Percent_Match"

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The relevant article is http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281998

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
   Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
   Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

   'Use the ADO connection that Access uses
   Set cn = CurrentProject.AccessConnection

   'Create an instance of the ADO Recordset class, and
   'set its properties
   Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
   With rs
      Set .ActiveConnection = cn
      .Source = "SELECT * FROM Customers"
      .LockType = adLockOptimistic
      .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
      .Open 
   End With

   'Set the form's Recordset property to the ADO recordset
   Set Me.Recordset = rs

   Set rs = Nothing
   Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

So in this particular case, you can try:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Cat_Percent_Match"
Set Forms.Cat_Percent_Match.Recordset = rs1
```